# Supervised Learning HMM with Pomegranate

Tags: python, hidden-markov-models, supervised-learning, pomegranate

thanks for your help, I am new about this topic.

I have a dataset composed of a sequence of binary observable variables associated with a label, like this.

```
trainset = [ [0,0,1,0],[0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,1],...,]
labels = [ 0,1,2,...,]
states = 3 # number of unique labels
```

I am trying to train an HMM in this way

```
model = HiddenMarkovModel.from_samples(distribution = MultivariateGaussianDistribution, n_components = states,
                                       X= [trainset],
                                       labels = [labels],
                                       algorithm = 'labeled')
```

When I ran this model, I get this Exception

> Exception ignored in:
> 'pomegranate.hmm.HiddenMarkovModel._labeled_summarize' KeyError: `3`

I figure out that the exception is raised when there are no observations for the state -`3`-.
But , state `3` is in my labels.
Can someone help me, please?
thanks

Comment: If there are 3 states I would expect labels 0,1,2. So maybe there are actually 4 states?Also be careful not to mix number and strings for the labels. 1! = '1'. Recommend print(set(labels)) to see the unique values